# Can't find files after installing jquery ui via nuget in .net core application

Tags: visual-studio, jquery-ui, nuget

When using nuget with the command 'Install-Package jQuery.UI.Combined -Version 1.12.1' in a .net core application, it seems to succeed except that I do not see where the files were installed to. Looking in wwwroot/lib reveals nothing. I'm sure I could just manually copy over the files and make it work, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using a package manager.

I only just started playing with .Net Core and maybe this is a known issue, or maybe I'm doing something wrong... I don't know. But if anyone could shed some light on this I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I used NPM (which I've never used before until now) and found that I also needed to install a bundler/minifier extension for visual studio. Using this I managed to bundle my js files, but first required that I create a new js file to bundle into, which I saved in my wwwroot folder. Then I just added a reference to the bundled js file in my view and it worked.

Steps taken:

1. Install package via npm
2. Right click gulpfile.js and select bundler and minifier
3. bundleconfig.json is updated
4. Create js file in wwwroot/js folder where minified file while be created
5. In bundleconfig.json change outputfilename of your packages to same location as step 4 (eg. "wwwroot/js/app-bundle.min.js")
6. Right click bundleconfig.json and update bundles
7. Include minified js in your view

[image]
[image]

Comment: And how did you solved the jquery issue you asked for in the first place? I dont understand how the bundle relates to it. I have my bundleconfig perfectly set

Comment: As I have explained, I was only familiar with nuget package manager until I started using .Net Core.  I have since become familiar with npm and webpack and also have my package managers working correctly. I'm guessing nuget only works with serverside packages in a .Net Core project, and front-end package managers like npm should be used for any js packages.

It would have been more useful for someone to provide some kind of a step-by-step process to getting things set up, rather than "I have my bundleconfig perfectly set" ... congrats, but some guidance would have been appreciated instead.